# Subtracting one time column from another r

Tags: r, time, types, difference

I'm trying to work out the time differences between two columns

```
Time_1       Time_2
17:16:40     17:17:52
12:42:07     12:42:54
12:14:43     12:21:37
12:10:42     12:13:53
12:03:39     12:05:18

typeof(Time_1)
[1] "double"

typeof(Time_2)
[1] "double"

DF <- data.frame(Time_1, Time_2)
str(DF)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DF.Time_1: 'times' num  NA 17:16:40 12:42:07 12:14:43 12:10:42 ...
  ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
 $ DF.Time_2: 'times' num  NA 17:17:52 12:42:54 12:21:37 12:13:53 ...
  ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
```

BUT, when I try to conduct the following subtraction

```
DF$Diff <- (DF$Time_2 - Tbl$Time_1)
```

I get very small decimals in the Diff column.

```
Time_1       Time_2      Diff
17:16:40     17:17:52    8.333333e-04
12:42:07     12:42:54    5.439815e-04
12:14:43     12:21:37    4.791667e-03
12:10:42     12:13:53    2.210648e-03
12:03:39     12:05:18    1.388889e-03
```

Can anyone tell me how I could get the Diff column to show in format HH:MM:SS?

Thanks

Comment: If you specify the package used, it would be great

Comment: Your calculations are correct, they are just in days - `72/(24*60*60)` = 0.0008333 days. As akrun suggests, if you can use `dput(DF)` so we know the structure of the data, it will probably be reasonably simple to convert it to H:M:S.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `times` from `chron` and then take the difference

```
library(dplyr)
library(chron)
DF %>% 
     mutate_all(times) %>% 
     mutate(Diff = Time_2 - Time_1)
#   Time_1   Time_2     Diff
#1 17:16:40 17:17:52 00:01:12
#2 12:42:07 12:42:54 00:00:47
#3 12:14:43 12:21:37 00:06:54
#4 12:10:42 12:13:53 00:03:11
#5 12:03:39 12:05:18 00:01:39
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(Time_1 = c("17:16:40", "12:42:07", "12:14:43", 
"12:10:42", "12:03:39"), Time_2 = c("17:17:52", "12:42:54", "12:21:37", 
"12:13:53", "12:05:18")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```